# Uncaught TypeError: this._propertySetter is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, web, polymer

I am trying to build my personal website using Polymer, and suddenly these errors came.

Please help me if you know the solution.

Thanks.

```
> Uncaught TypeError: this._propertySetter is not a function app-route.html:398
>     at HTMLElement.__setMulti (app-route.html:398)
>     at HTMLElement.__tryToMatch (app-route.html:324)
>     at Object.runMethodEffect [as fn] (property-effects.html:772)
>     at runEffectsForProperty (property-effects.html:137)
>     at runEffects (property-effects.html:103)
>     at HTMLElement._propertiesChanged (property-effects.html:1533)
>     at HTMLElement._flushProperties (property-accessors.html:496)
>     at HTMLElement._flushClients (property-effects.html:1442)
>     at HTMLElement._propertiesChanged (property-effects.html:1529)
>     at HTMLElement._flushProperties (property-accessors.html:496)
```

Comment: can you try to console.log that function inside one of your elements ? . Just write console.log(this._propertySetter) inside one of your elements. And tell me what is the output

Comment: the same result Uncaught TypeError: this._propertySetter is not a function app-route.html:398. i've try to console.log("test") and doesn't show anything

Comment: then i tried to put the console.log(this._propertySetter) on app.route.html, the result is 'undefined'

Comment: are you using compatible elements? you could download newer version of app-route and remain old polymer. In `bower.json` you can find all versions. what version is your polymer and app-route ?

Comment: 'm using app-route#^0.9.0, and polymer#^1.6.0. should i download both newer version? where can i download it?

Comment: seems like polymer 1.6.0 is old and missing that one function because i didn't find it. try to update your polymer. `bower update polymer --save` to at least version 1.8 or 1.9/1.9.1

Comment: @AchmadFikriSyarif It would be more helpful if you provide a GitHub link to your source (or a sample project that reproduces the problem) in order for us to provide more helpful/accurate answers. Can you update your question with the GitHub link?